# Wordpress - The loop - With categories instead of posts

Tags: wordpress, loops, paging, categories

There are [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and [WP Query object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). They are helpful to loop out posts and pages.

**Category loop**

I have 1500 categories and in the future there might be 15000 posts. Each category is important which is why I want to loop them out, like the loop (like it does with single posts).

I can't really figure it out. I came across [get_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) but it does not support paging.